# SQL geometry find points outside shape

Tags: sql, sql-server, geospatial

In Microsoft SQL Server I have a table MyData which has a column of latlng of geometry type. I am trying to figure out how to write a query that gets all the points that are not in the USA, I would even be fine with everything outside a rectangular box that stretches from Alaska to Florida and includes Canada. Once I know how to do it then i know I can always draw a more complex polygon which is the countries I need.  Thanks!

Comment: good point. i updated. i am using microsoft sql server

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
declare @us geography = geography::STGeomFromText(«WKT for US», 4326)
set @us = @us.MakeValid()

declare @cities table (name varchar(100), geo geography)
insert into @cities (name, geo) values 
    ('London', geography::Point(51.5074, -0.1278,  4326)),
    ('Boston', geography::Point(42.3601, -71.0589, 4326));

select name, geo.STIntersects(@us)
from @cities as c
```

I got the WKT for the United States boundary through slightly convoluted means. That is, I went to [Census Bureau](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_nation.html) and downloaded a shapefile and then used a[n online tool](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) to convert it to WKT. If you have a better source for that WKT, use it.

The meat of the solution though is in the `STIntersects()` call. That method returns a boolean as to whether two geospatial instances intersect or not. In this case, because one is a point and the other is a multi-polygon, it will tell you if the point is within the boundary. You could also use `STDisjoint()` to tell the opposite (i.e. that method returns true if the point is *not* within the boundary). Good hunting.